# Blueimp multiple input elements with their own urls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

So I have multiple input elements that use blueimp to upload files and folders, each having their own link to a path on the server. Each element is intended to upload the files to their respective urls, which they do; however, I want them to upload independently upon the drop of a file/folder. For instance, if I drop a folder onto the first input element, then that element solely uploads the files to its url and no other input element triggers/uploads; however, the behavior I'm getting is that if I drop the folder on one, they all upload the folder.

Here's an example of what my current form and inputs look like:

```
<form name = "self" action = "http://localhost/proj/index.html" method = "post">
    <input class="fileupload" id="fileupload0" type="file" name="files[]"  multiple>
    <input class="fileupload" id="fileupload1" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input class="fileupload" id="fileupload2" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</form>
```

These are created and initialized in a for loop in php, the inside looking like this:

```
echo "<input class = 'fileupload' id ='fileupload$numinput' type='file' name='files[]'multiple>";
echo "<script>init($numinput, $myUniqueLink)</script>";
$numinput++;
```

$myUniqueLink also changes in the for loop.

Here's how I initialize them:

```
function init(num, link) {
    $(function () {
          $('#fileupload' + num).fileupload({
              maxChunkSize: 10000000,
              dataType: 'json',
              url: link,
           });
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your `fileupload` css class look like? Have you tried putting large spacing divs, `<div style="margin: 100px;"></div>`, between each input to ensure the dragged file is not just dragging onto all three inputs.

Comment: They don't overlap. I actually figured out how to do what I asked. However, now I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make my dropzones greedy like in the JQuery Droppable widget.

Comment: Please post an answer with how you got it working so that future visitors may see it. Thanks.